# Using window."plugin" cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

This is an easy answer however I don't know where to go. How do I use the window. code, I have searched the internet for weeks. I am trying to implement a geofence feature, however I notice Cordova uses a window.** format now. I looked for materials to read up on it but I'm stuck.... I'm trying to implement the plugin https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence
, I can only use the methods:

- window.geofence.initialize(onSuccess, onError)
- window.geofence.addOrUpdate(geofences, onSuccess, onError)
- window.geofence.remove(geofenceId, onSuccess, onError)
- window.geofence.removeAll(onSuccess, onError)
- window.geofence.getWatched(onSuccess, onError)

in the index.js file, because I don't have a clue how to implement them elsewhere, such as a service...

Please help. Thank you.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
  if ($window.geofence === undefined) {
    $log.warn("Geofence Plugin not found. Using mock instead.");
    $window.geofence = window.geofence
    $window.TransitionType = window.TransitionType;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I had to inject $document, as well as $window, in the service I wanted to use it at, in order to use
window."plugin name", somewhere other than the onCreate function in index.js

Answer (score 1):

You may draw inspiration from the **ngCordova** module.
For example the $cordovaGeolocation service (or another one):

- the original Cordova plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation
- $cordovaGeolocation documentation: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/
- $cordovaGeolocation source: https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/blob/master/src/plugins/geolocation.js

Check also this Ionic geofence example: https://github.com/cowbell/ionic-geofence

PS: in cordova-plugin-geolocation the plugin APIs are attached to "navigator" (instead of window). I.e.: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()